# How to use zero_width_space for text wrapping

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I found this piece of code which wraps the data inside a cell ,but it doesn't take into account the word i.e if the complete word cannot be fitted in the line ,It doesn't change the line .It writes few alphabets before changing the line .

What should I modify in this code so that If a particular word is not getting adjusted in the line , it changes the line .

Also , I am new to xsl -fo .I have understood most of the code ,but would appreciate if a little could be explained .

```
 <xsl:template name="zero_width_space_1">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:param name="counter" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$counter &lt; string-length($data)">
          <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")'/>
           <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_2">
               <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="zero_width_space_2">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:param name="counter"/>
       <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")'/>
       <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    and then placing a call to zero_width_space_1 like following-

    <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="span"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

for ex - "I found this piece of code which wraps the data inside a cell "..It shows as in a cell as

```
I found th
is piece o
f code whi
ch wraps t
he data in
side a cel
l
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of text that doesn't work properly?

Comment: Have edited my answer . Should this code be working ??

Comment: It is working as it's written to do.  It's putting a ZERO WIDTH SPACE between every character so that lines can break between any two characters.  If you didn't use it, lines would break only at the space characters.  What text do you want to break?  If it's words you'd find in a dictionary, then you should look at using the hyphenation support build into your FO formatter.

Comment: These templates add a zero-width space after each character of the *data* parameter; the result is that words could be split (ending a line, and starting a new one) in any position, regardless of proper hyphenation rules. If you want to avoid words to be split like this (which would be the normal behaviour), you don't have to modify the templates: you just have to avoid calling them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping is provided by the cells automatically . Zero_width_space includes a zero-width space after every character ,so better to not call this template if the requirement is not filling the cells character wise .